# How implement this option ? {iPhone SDK}

Tags: iphone

is there any way to program this option in xcode ? i don't think so this is text Alignment , it's something like text direction on microsoft office !

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what it is exactly that you want to do? Are you asking to have text flow right-to-left, or just be aligned to the right side (or something else entirely)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This button is available when the user is using a RTL-language keyboard, e.g. Arabic or Hebrew. This button just switches the writing direction between LTR and RTL. There is no need to implement it yourself.

Comment: yes exactly , i create custom persian keyboard for iPad and i wanna my textview automatically be RTL direction  , without user touch this option

Comment: @Momeks: For jailbroken platform or not?

Comment: no ! for non-jailbroken my application is available on app store iam working on new update for that

Comment: @Momeks: Then you can't have this button without Private API.

Comment: anyway , is there any way to mix english and persian text together ? like that option ?

Comment: @Momeks: That option and mixing English/Persian are two separate things. The latter is always possible.